# When using BackdropFilter in ListView, BackdropFilter is disabled at the timing of the stretching overscroll effect

Tags: flutter, shader, flutter-listview, material3, flutter-material

In Android's Material3 environment, the ListView's ScrollBehavior is by default the StretchingOverscrollIndicator.

Therefore, when using a blur Container(Like Neumorphism / Glassmorphism design) with BackdropFilter as a ListView item, I have noticed that the blur disappears when over scrolling in Android environment.

The following is a code that can reproduce issue.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Text('a' * 10000),
    ListView.separated(
      itemCount: 2,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ClipRect(
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
    ),
  ],
)
```

---

Full code(main.dart)

*Reproducible issue in outside of the Android environment.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      /* For non-Android devices, the same phenomenon can be observed by activating the code below. */
      // builder: (context, child) => ScrollConfiguration(
      //   behavior: const ScrollBehaviorModified(),
      //   child: child!,
      // ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class ScrollBehaviorModified extends ScrollBehavior {
  const ScrollBehaviorModified();

  @override
  Widget buildOverscrollIndicator(
      BuildContext context, Widget child, ScrollableDetails details) {
    return StretchingOverscrollIndicator(
      axisDirection: details.direction,
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: child,
    );
  }

  @override
  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {
        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,
        PointerDeviceKind.trackpad,
      };
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Text('a' * 10000),
          ListView.separated(
            itemCount: 2,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ClipRect(
              child: BackdropFilter(
                filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Since the blur disappears not only in the ListView, but also at the timing of the screen transition animation, I think the problem is related to shaders.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

I am looking for a solution other than disabling the ListView's StretchingOverscrollIndicator if possible.
(This is because the issue of blur disappearing also occurs in animations during screen transitions.)

---

**Added**

I found the same Issue in the Flutter project on GitHub.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/138940

It works fine in Flutter 3.13 and seems to cause problems in Flutter 3.16 and later.

So, as a temporary solution, I will use Flutter 3.13 and wait for the above Issue on GitHub to be resolved.

Comment: try look here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126353

Comment: @VladyslavUlianytskyi
Thanks! I had already checked that page once.

I thought that Issue (#126353) was a performance degradation issue, which is different issue from the BackdropFilter being disabled all the time during the stretching overscroll effect like this one.